# Inspecting memory allocation,leaks using Instruments tool

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, memory-management, instruments

[image]

As suggested by many,instruments tool is the best way to capture the memory allocation and leaks.But for me its been easy to use instruments tool,but i am confused with the detailed results as shown in the above screenshot.

Want to know the meaning of following points,
1)All Allocations,
2)Live Bytes,
3)Overall Bytes,
4)Overall.

Simple but confusing!Any answer will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**live bytes:** The number of bytes that have been allocated but not released yet.
**Living:***The number of object created and still on the heap.
**Transitory:**  The number of objects created and destroyed
**Overall byte: The total number of byte that have been allocated and released

*overall***:The total number of objects allocated and released .
**all allocations**: All the allocations while the application is running .