# Will using the JSContext from a UIWebview get my app rejcted?

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, uiwebview, webkit

We have a requirement in our app wherein we have to communicate across the web/native boundary - between JavaScript running in a `UIWebView` and ObjectiveC in the app.

The web component communicates internally via pagebus(a subscription and publishing mechanism) and the requirement is that the  native component should also be capable enough to subscribe for those events and listen to them.

We all know that the only official way to call into a `UIWebView` from ObjectiveC is via `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString`.  And the typical way to call out from JavaScript is some manner of setting window.location to trigger a `shouldStartLoadWithRequest:` callback on the `UIWebView` delegate. But this will be not useful to handle page bus events.

Apple gives us a public JavaScriptCore framework (part of WebKit) in iOS7, and JavaScriptCore provides simple mechanisms to proxy objects and methods between ObjectiveC and the JavaScript “context”.

Unfortunately, to make use of this framework in achieving our objective, we need the JSContext object of the webview, but there is no mechanism to achieve it. There is a stack overflow link where we found there are two approaches to achieve this (both undocumented).

Approach 1: Get the JSContext via KVC

```
JSContext *ctx = [webView valueForKeyPath:@"documentView.webView.mainFrame.javaScriptContext"];
```

Approach 2:
Get the JSContext via WebKit's `-didCreateJavaScriptContext` delegate callback.

Please find the reference link below
[Why use JavaScriptCore in iOS7 if it can't access a UIWebView's runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18920536/why-use-javascriptcore-in-ios7-if-it-cant-access-a-uiwebviews-runtime)
The question is can we use either of these methods in our app, so that our app won't get rejected in App Store
Or is there any other mechanism to achieve our objective  of listening to pagebus events?

Comment: You may want to refine your question slightly. Perhaps have the last question as "Will our app be rejected if we directly access the JSContext from a UIWebView as it is not available via standard means?" or something. I'm asking the same question right now.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think apple will rejected your app. I use kvc to get jscontext from uiwebview in my app and it pass the app review.